# How &multi[3][0] and *(multi + 3) are same thing?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose we have an multi dimensional array.

```
multi[3][10]
```

then `&multi[0][0]`will be **multi**

if we want to access any element in this array. we need just one dereferencing. as it is located in continuously. i am not able to understand double dereferencing. 
as

```
*(*(multi+row)+column)
```

Comment: "`&multi[0][0]` will be `multi`" - no it won't. It'll probably print identically if you try to printf it, but their types are quite different. Dereferencing the first will produce an entirely different result from dereferencing the second.

Comment: What is the type ?

Comment: @SaketAnand; You don't know "type", seriously?

Comment: I mean what will be the type of both.

Comment: Type of multi is *array of 3 arrays of 10 `int`* (assuming `int` data type of elements). In any expression except when an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&`  it will be converted to `int (*)[10]` (pointer to an array of 10 `int`).

Answer (score 2):

`&multi[0][0]` is address of the first element of array `multi` which is equivalent to `multi[0]`.

`multi` is an array of 1D arrays. `multi` will decay to pointer to it's first element when used in an expression except when an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&`.
In the expression

```
*(*(multi+row)+column)
```

The inner `*` is to dereference a 1D array (a row)  and the outer `*` is to dereference the element of that row.

```
*(multi + row) => multi[row] 
*(*(multi+row)+column) => *(multi[row] + column) => multi[row][column]
```

Comment: You mean multi[0] is a pointer. So printing it should give address. But it is  giving  the value instead.

Comment: `multi[0]` is an array of 10 `int`. Decay rule will be applied to it like other arrays.

Comment: No. It should be `int (*ptr)[10] = multi;`.

Comment: And int *ptr = multi[0] are same ?

Comment: Thanks you very much